# IE9 error SEC7111 ("HTTPS security is compromised") when using the Facebook REST API

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-9

I'm the author of a Wordpress plugin that allows users to login to their blogs with Facebook; it uses the old REST API to introduce the login button.  Typically, including the API is done via the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
```

However, after Facebook introduced secure connections (Account -> Account Settings -> Account Security -> Secure Browsing), the Connect popups broke.  One plugin user pointed out that the issue could be fixed by replacing the above with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
```

Everything works fine now in every browser except the newly released IE9, which reports the following two errors (and refuses to initialize the Facebook API):

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php?api_key=(MY_KEY)&extern=0&channel=(URL_to_my_xd_receiver)

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://api.facebook.com/static/v0.4/client_restserver.php?r=1300118768

Note that the page hosting the Facebook Connect button is not https, and the preceding two script includes were not added by me - viewing the page DOM source via IE9's developer tools reveals that those two scripts are included within a div "FB_HiddenContainer", which is apparently inserted asynchronously by Facebook as it tries to initialize.

Everything I've found on Google regarding SEC7111 refers to https pages trying to include scripts via http, but my problem is the opposite: the page is http, and the scripts (being loaded automatically by Facebook) are https.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty stumped.  If you'd like to play with it yourself you can do so on my site, http://www.justin-klein.com.  You'll note that the "Login with Facebook" button initializes properly on all browsers but IE9.

Comment: I really can't help you and I'm pretty sure that you thought about it, but I have to ask...Have you considered upgrading the plugin?

Comment: Of course.  It's nontrivial to do so though and I'm very short on time at the moment, so I would really like to avoid rewriting everything just to cater to IE if possible...

Comment: @Metal450 Any update on your issues? I'm getting the same error when I try to send a get variable to my Canvas app (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7866581/ie9-error-sec7111-https-security-is-compromised-after-redirect-plus-only-secu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that using the https FB library. More info [here](http://geek-to-geek.com/48/error-sec7111-https-security-compromised-login-with-facebook).

From a cached version of that site:

> *SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=0.*
>
> This error can be fixed using the https version:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Hey Rafael,Thanks for the tip - unfortunately, that's the new API, so using that would require rewriting every call to a different format (both on the Javascript and PHP sides).  As mentioned in my comment above, doing so is a pretty nontrivial undertaking and I was really hoping for an easier solution than "redoing the whole plugin" just to get it to work with IE9...

Comment: It looks like there was no way around this with the old API, and updating was the only solution.  Thus, answer accepted.

Comment: The only thing that link suggests is using https instead of http. I tried that, does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: The link is dead, this is a good example of why the relevant portion of the link should be copy/pasted into the answer